# why my c program to split string into tokens prints nothing

Tags: c, strtok

I have code in C for splitting a sample string into tokens using the `strtok()` function. I seem to have followed everything by the book but my CLion compiler does not print the individual string tokens and exits the script with this code `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. Below is how I am trying to split the string, help me debug the issue.

```
//declare and assign the sentence I need to split
char * sentence ="Cat,Dog,Lion";
//declare and assign the delimiter 
char * delim=",";
//get the first token
char * token = strtok(sentence, delim);
while(token!= NULL){
     //print a single string token
      printf("%s",token);
      //reset the loop for the iteration to continue
      token = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
```

Comment: You should enable all compiler warnings that you can find, and please format your code consistently.

Comment: Compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) debugger, and read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the documentation of your compiler and your debugger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) will write null characters into the string pointed to by its first argument. Therefore, that string must be writable. However, you are supplying a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), which is read-only. Attempting to write to a string literal will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simplest fix to your problem would therefore be to change the line

```
char * sentence ="Cat,Dog,Lion";
```

to:

```
char sentence[] = "Cat,Dog,Lion";
```

That way, `sentence` will be a writable array, instead of a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer let me try this out